# determine type of singularities and compute residue of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Determine the type of singularities and residue of $$\frac{1}{\sin^2(z)}$$

For this problem, this is the way I approach this: 
we have : 
$$\sin(z) = z - \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^5}{5!} - \cdots$$
$$= z\left(1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{5!} - \cdots\right)$$
Let $h(z) = 1 - \frac{z^2}{3!} + \frac{z^4}{5!} - \cdots$. Then, we have: 
$$\sin(z) = z\cdot h(z)$$
$$\sin^2(z) = z^2 \cdot h^2(z)$$
Therefore, 
$$\frac{1}{\sin^2(z)} = \frac{1}{z^2} \cdot \frac{1}{h^2(z)}$$
Thus, it has a simple pole at $z_0 = 0$.
But, I don't know how to calculate the residue of this function. Can someone please how me how to compute its residue.

Comment: Note that it's not a simple pole, it's a double pole.  There are also double poles at $z=n\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a double pole (**note**: not a simple pole) at $z=0$, so there will be a Laurent series
$$\frac1{\sin^2z}=\frac{A}{z^2}+\frac{B}{z}+C+Dz+Ez^2+\cdots$$
and the residue is $B$.  But since the LHS is an even function, the coefficients $B,D$ etc of odd powers of $z$ are all zero.  Thus the residue is $0$.

Note that there are also double poles at $z=n\pi$ and you can use the above to find the relevant series at these points:
$$\frac1{\sin^2z}=\frac1{\sin^2(z-n\pi)}=\frac{A}{(z-n\pi)^2}+C
  +E(z-n\pi)^2+\cdots\ .$$

Comment: can you please show me the formal way to find the residue of this function ?

Comment: My answer **is** a formal way to do it!!  Alternatively, you could compute$$\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{(z-z_0)^2}{\sin^2z}\ \ldots$$... if you like doing things the hard way ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.  For the pole at $z=0$, let's write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sin^2 z}&=\frac{1}{\left(z-\frac16 z^3++O(z^5)\right)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{z^2\left(1-\frac16 z^2++O(z^4)\right)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{\left(1+\frac16 z^2+O(z^4)\right)^2}{z^2}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac13+O(z^2)
\end{align}$$

Thus, we find the singularity is a pole of order $2$.

We can perform a similar expansion for around any of the zeros of the sine function and see that there are singularities of $\csc^2 z$ that are poles of order $2$ at $z=n\pi$ for all integer values of $n$.

Another way to see this is to recall the infinite product representation of the sine function.  Then,

$$\sin z=z\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$$

implies that

$$\csc^2 z=\frac{1}{z^2 \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)^2}$$

which clearly shows the second order poles at $z=n\pi$.

Comment: can you show me how can you find the residue of this function ?

Comment: @Alexander Since the coefficient on $z^{-1}$ term is zero, the residue is zero.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to help and give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Hi sir, I think your answer is really good and detail though. But, in my opinion,  just the way that David wrote his answer made me easier to understand.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you for your comment.  And I understand. If you think my answer was at all useful as a supplement, please feel free to give it a vote up as you see fit.